# Выбрать и вывести только 1 строчку из таблицы sqlite

Tags: java, sqlite, javafx, search, filter

Подскажите, как я могу вывести записи из таблицы согласно введенному в текстовое поле `Id` (`searchBox` — `fx:id` текстовое поле для ввода `id`)?

Пытался сделать следующим способом:

```
@FXML
private void searchUser(ActionEvent event) {
    String sqlfiltr = ("SELECT * FROM teachers WHERE id = '"+searchBox+"'");

    try{
        Connection conn = dbConnection.getConnection();
        this.data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(sqlfiltr);
        while (rs.next()){
            this.data.add(new TeacherData(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4), rs.getString(5)));
        }

    } catch (SQLException e){
        System.err.println("Oshibka "  + e);
    }
    this.idTableColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TeacherData, String>("ID"));
    this.fnamecolum.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TeacherData, String>("firstname"));
    this.lnamecolum.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TeacherData, String>("lastname"));
    this.emailcolum.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TeacherData, String>("email"));
    this.coursecolum.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TeacherData, String>("course"));

    this.teachertable.setItems(null);
    this.teachertable.setItems(this.data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

А что за ошибка возникает?

Вообще я бы написал так:

```
String sqlfiltr = ("SELECT * FROM teachers WHERE id = " + searchBox);
```

Если id число, то ' ' не нужны вроде как.

Comment: Ошибка не возникала, просто проходило и таблицу не заполняло. Попробовал так, как вы предложили:         Oshibka org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "[id=searchBox, styleClass=text-input text-field]": syntax error)

Comment: а так:

String sqlfiltr = ("SELECT * FROM teachers WHERE id = ?");

PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlfiltr);
stmt.setString(1, searchBox);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Попробовал так. В принципе он выбирает нужную строку и выводит ее в таблицу, но на позицию ниже имеющихся записей, т.е. он дописывает в таблицу выбранную по id строку. Не подскажете каким образом я могу очистить таблицу, а затем занести туда только 1 эту строку?

Comment: @studer выводится все содержимое  this.data. Если вам надо выводить только новую строку, просто очистите коллекцию от старых элементов

Comment: @Виктор Спасибо, я и не подумал. Помогло.